# In Fable 3, what is the rent/profit payoff time interval?

Tags: fable-3

In Fable 2 i think it was every 5 minutes, regardless if the game was playing.  Any idea what the interval for rent/profit payout is on Fable 3?

Comment: A better option is to simply go inside a shop that won't close at night, get behind the counter and stuff your 360 controller in between your sofa cushions, then try to make it such that your character spins around so the system won't detect if you're away from controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rent & profit is paid every 5 minutes, but only if you are playing the game. The rent is paid even if you leave your Xbox alone and the screen dims.

You do not get paid while in the Sanctuary or any of its connected rooms, but not including the Road to Rule.

Answer (score 7):

If 5 minutes since the last payout has passed you will received money and the timer resets.

This means no matter how much time has passed you can get paid a maximum of once

It's also worth noting you can't get paid in the interactive menue

Answer (score -1):

Every 5 minutes, I get 50K gold, so the time interval is probably 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

5 minutes although you must be renting out a house or own a shop to earn money this way